# Celery, RabbitMQ and Django on Heroku: Reaching Memory Limit

Tags: django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery

I'm reaching the RAM memory limit on my Heroku Dyno (hobby) currently while running Celery tasks with RabbitMQ in a Django app.

I'm played around with the Celery settings a little bit but I keep hitting the memory limit, and I'm missing the technical knowledge on memory optimization. I'm wondering if there is anything I can do with my current settings to prevent reaching the limit or is the only solution here to upgrade the Heroku Dyno?

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://url'
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 5
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None
CELERY_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 10
CELERY_MAX_MEMORY_PER_CHILD = 80000
```

```
Procfile:web: gunicorn app_name.wsgi worker: celery -A app_name worker -l info --without-heartbeat
```

```
Task.py file:@shared_task(acks_late=True, ignore_result=True)
def function_name(args):
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and setting the max concurrency to 2 or 3 solved the problem.

In your procfile, add `-c 2` or `-c 3` in the worker definition.

By default, Celery will set the concurrency to the number of CPUs available. And the concurrency defines the number of celery workers that will spawn.